# Prove that there exists an analytic function $f : D → D$ such that $f(1/2) = f(−1/2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is an old qualifying exam problem that I am working on.  I would appreciate some help.  Thank you.

Prove that there exists an analytic function $f : D → D$ such that $f(1/2) = f(−1/2)$
and $f′(z) \neq 0$ for all $z ∈ D.$

Comment: The exponential function is periodic and its derivative vanishes nowhere.

Comment: How is the exponential function periodic?

Comment: $e^{2\pi i z} = e^{2\pi i (z+n)}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 4):

Expanding the hint by Daniel Fischer: $f(z) = c \exp(2\pi iz)$ works when $|c|$  is small enough so that $f(D)\subset D$.

Comment: You'll have troubles if $D$ is not bounded....

Comment: @Hurkyl Or if $D$ does not contain $\pm 1/2$. :) I read between the lines that $D$ is $\mathbb D$, the unit disk.